# Second Site Channel URL Route Not Working

Tags: routing, multi-site

I've set up a Resources section on a multi-site installation with the type of Channel. For Site 1 I've set the routing rule to be `{resourcesParent.one.slug}/{slug}` and for Site 2 I've set the rule as `{slug}`.

[image]

So for Site 1 a resource titled `sample-resource` would resolve to `www.example.com/parent-slug/sample-resource`.

And for Site 2 it would resolve as `sub.example.com/sample-resource`

Everything works fine for Site 1, however when I go to `sub.example.com/sample-resource` I get a "template not found: sample-resource" 404 error.

Seems like this should work so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: I just noticed that `sub.example.com/parent-slug/sample-resource` is resolving, so I think something's wrong with my config. Here's what I have for my dev environment in `craft/config/general.php`:

```
'dev' => [
    'siteUrl' => array(
        '//www.example.com',
        '//sub.example.com'
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add `define('CRAFT_SITE', 'sub');` to the `index.php` file on my Site 2 web root.